# Z-score to Percentile from in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mean

Given the fact that I can compute my z-score for a given observation:

i.e. I have variables for 'SAMPLE MEAN', 'POPULATION MEAN' and 'POPULATION STANDARD DEVIATION'.

Is there a way/function in MYSQL to computes the Percentile number from a given Z-score?

For instance, if: sample mean=3.67, pop_mean=3.92, pop_sd=0.65 then, z_score = (3.67-3.92)/0.65 = -0.38  => Percentile= 34%.

I haven't found relevant literature about it.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I expect that it could be done with some sql as something like:

Assuming this table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE stats (zscore DOUBLE, link INTEGER autoincrement); 
CREATE TABLE summary (sample_mean DOUBLE, pop_mean DOUBLE, pop_stdev DOUBLE, link INTEGER autoincrement);

SELECT 
  sts.zscore, 
  smm.sample_mean, 
  smm.pop_mean, 
  smm.pop_stdev, 
  (smm.pop_mean + (sts.zscore * smm.pop_stdev)) as percentile 
FROM stats sts 
JOIN summary smm ON sts.link = smm.link
```

It's been a bit since I've worked with MySQL directly, but that should do the trick.

You can also do it with unions and group bys but that is a little more complex than most people want.

Comment: Hi: your code does not answer the question. It does not compute the expected percentile (here 34).